# .Net Core 2.1 and Angular 6 Cookies

Tags: angular, cookies, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a little private Project and now I'm hanging with cookies.

First of all I want to show you some code:

UserServiceControler.cs

```
[HttpPost("IsAuthenticated")]
public IActionResult IsAuthenticated([FromBody] IsAuthenticatedRequest request) {
 var hash = _userService.IsAuthenticated(HttpContext, request);
 switch (hash) {
  case "200":
  case "401":
     return new StatusCodeResult(Convert.ToInt32(hash));
  default:
     if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Contains("TEST")) {
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("TEST");
     }
     HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("Test", hash, new CookieOptions() {
         HttpOnly = true,
         Secure = true,
         IsEssential = true,
         Domain = "localhost",
         Expires = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).AddMinutes(20.0)
    });
    return new StatusCodeResult(200);
 }
}
```

Proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://localhost:5001",
    "secure": false,
    "topLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  },
  "/login.html": {
    "target": "http://localhost:4200/assets/pages",
    "secure": false
  }, 
  "/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:4200",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

login.html just function

```
var paramString = "{username: \"test\", password: \"test\"}";
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    window.location.href = "/";
  } else if (this.status == 401) {
    alert("1");
  }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "/api/UserService/IsAuthenticated", true);
xhttp.withCredentials = true;
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json-patch+json");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
xhttp.send(paramString);
```

When I test my IsAuthenticated via Swagger, I get my cookie with all I want. But when I want to use this in my Angular app, i don't get my cookie.

How does it works:
Normally when I call `/api/UserService/IsAuthenticated`, in swagger, and give him a username and a password it sets the cookie in my browser. This makes my happy because this shows me that my api is not the problem.
Now it comes to Angular.
I start my app via `npm start` and this makes that `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json` nothing special.
In my index.html is the same code as in login.html just with test username and password because it looks at the cookie in my api.
So I go to `localhost:4200`. First it should redirect me to `localhost:4200/login.html` because I'm not logged in. This works.
Now in login.html I give him my username and my password --> wait some ms --> and i get StatusCode 200 and in my Brower Console at network i see my request with a response cookie. But it isn't set in my browser. This is not good. That I get redirected to `localhost:4200` because StatusCode is 200 and at `index.html` he checks again if i'm Authenticated and I get redirected back to `localhost:4200/login.html` because of cookie is not there.

Can anyone help me please with this cookie problem? Or is there a better way how I can make this user session?

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say *But it isn't set in my browser.*?

Comment: When you press `F12` then go to storage and then cookies, e.g. there should be a stackoverflow cookie now. When I test it in Swagger I have my own Cookie there too. But not when I do it with Angular

Comment: Have you used [`AllowCredentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.allowcredentials?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in your ASP.NET Core project's CORS configuration?

Comment: Just tried, but nothing changed

Comment: Are you actively doing anything to save the cookie? Like setting document.cookie the token you receive from the API?

Comment: mmh.. nope. How can I do this? Because xhttp.getResponseHeader('set-cookie') is empty

Comment: When I look in "Network" I can see the Response Header with "set-cookie" but I don't get it with xhttp.getResponseHeader('set-cookie')

Comment: I got from Chrome more info: Refused to get unsafe header "set-cookie"

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Not with cookies